# How to change an old commit message?

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit, git-commit

I need to change an old commit message. Considering that I've made a few other commits afterwards, is there a way to change it, via git or directly on GitHub, without interfering with the other commits?

Comment: Since a commit hash includes the hashes of its parent commits, changing any commit that has children changes the hashes of the entire child tree.

Comment: To amplify @BenjaminW.'s comment a bit: this does "interfere with" the other commits, in that you've told Git that you would like to replace all the old commits, starting from the one you reword, with new-and-improved commits. The improvement is just to link back to the earlier improved commit, for all but the reworded commit. The drawback to doing this is that it's easy to make *your* Git repository comply, but then you need `--force` or similar to get the GitHub repository to update, and then *everyone who has the old commits* must *also* update.

Answer (score 15):

You can't use `git commit --amend` because it's not your most recent commit.

You would want to do a rebase, something similar to

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Where 3 would be how many commits back you'd like to go.

This is doing an interactive rebase. On the screen or text window that opens, replace `pick` with `reword`.

On the next screen or text window, you will then be able to change the commit message(s).

Doing a rebase changes the commit hashes, so you will need to do a `git push --force-with-lease` otherwise your changes will be rejected from the server.

`--force-with-lease` is generally safer than `--force` when doing potentially destructive commits.

See the [Amending older or multiple commit messages](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-and-editing-commits/changing-a-commit-message#amending-older-or-multiple-commit-messages) from the link @Myffo posted.

Answer (score 8):

To change an old commit's message you can use either

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

(4 is an arbitrary number instead of 4 you have to use the rank of the commit you want to change, most current commit is considered 1)

or

```
git rebase -i (SHA of the commit you want to edit)^
```

ex. git rebase -i 993ff4750f38b701383575a95b4efea54cc77658^

(don't forget to add '^' symbol at the end of your sha)

These commands will display the latest commits in your default text editor.
In that text editor find the commit you would like to change and replace 'pick' with 'reword'. After you save and exit. Another window will pop up for you to change the the message.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of rebasing and force pushing the modified branch, it's possible to replace a commit with a different message without affecting the existing commit hashes.

The syntax looks like this:

```
git replace --edit <commit>
```

This opens the editor and displays something like this:

```
tree 430db025986d2bf8791be16b370ec37a00f6924b
parent 77efdb98a6e021ca81cd96f7c8c05d25c09e0ad4
author John Doe <johndoe@example.org> 1698219601 +0200
committer John Doe <johndoe@example.org> 1698219601 +0200

<initial commit message>
```

Modify the message and save.

The modified references will then have to be pushed and fetched explicitly with:

```
git push origin 'refs/replace/*'
git fetch origin 'refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*'
```

This requires Git 2.1 or higher.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace

Comment: However, to distribute the replacement commit to other parties, extra effort is needed. In particular, the `refs/replace` hierarchy must be pushed and fetched.

Comment: @j6t good point thank you, I've mentioned it.